# Unable to click button using selenium for specific site

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def main(driver):
    driver.get("https://masscannabiscontrol.com/product-catalog/")
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn"))
        ).click()
    finally:
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    main(driver)
```

I still keep getting timeout Exception. what could be the reason as am trying to click on `I'm 21 Or Older`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main(driver):
    driver.get("https://masscannabiscontrol.com/product-catalog/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe"))
    )
   
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
         EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn"))
        )
    driver.execute_script(
        "arguments[0].scrollIntoView({'inline':'center','block':'center'})", element)
    element.click()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=firefox_capabilities)    
    main(driver)
```

The button is inside an iframe you have to switch to it first.

make sure to switch back to default content to interact again with elements outside of iframe

```
   driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Just tried that out. actually it's not doing anything. did you tried it on firefox ?

Comment: Replace `presence_of_element_located` with `element_to_be_clickable`

Comment: @vitaliis Thank you for the edit also make sure you scroll into that element if still it doesn't work

Comment: I wanted to answer, but @PDHide was first :)

Comment: there is open issues with selenium and gekodriver click : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/322

Answer (score 0):

This works on Chrome, not sure about Firefox

I took out the `try/finally` clause just to keep the window open to make sure it works

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def main(driver):
    driver.get("https://masscannabiscontrol.com/product-catalog/")
    iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@src='https://catalog.metrc.com/']")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn"))
    ).click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    main(driver)
```

As **PDHide** mentioned, you need to get into the iframe first before proceeding.  Also switch out of it once you are done using `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

EDIT: **PDHide** solution works fine for me in Chrome as well.  His is actually a more robust solution than mine.  It could be that you aren't noticing it working because the window is closing right away.  Or maybe it's a weird FireFox thing